# Cross Database Join Collation Issue

Tags: sql-server, union, collation

Having an issue with this join across Databases. When I run each section seperately (before/after the UNION) They run just fine. However, once the Union is in place I get errors.

> Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "Latin1_General_BIN" and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" in the UNION operation. >

When I try and over come this issue by adding COLLATE to Specific areas (Columns coming from the InspectionSpecification Table) of the Select Statement I then get a separate error.

> Error converting data type varchar to numeric. >

I've tried overcoming this by CASTing the fields to INTs to no avail...Any help would be appreciated.

```
Select  WJAL.Job
,StockCode
,StockDescription
,Complete
,WJAL.Operation
,IExpUnitRunTim
,ParentQtyPlanEnt
,OperCompleted
,QtyCompleted
,QtyScrapped
,WorkCentre
,JobStartDate
,ActualFinishDate
,LEFT(RIGHT(StockDescription, CASE WHEN 
                                LEN(StockDescription) - CHARINDEX(',', 
StockDescription) - 1 < 0 THEN 0 ELSE LEN(StockDescription) - CHARINDEX(',', 
StockDescription) - 1 END), CHARINDEX(' ', RIGHT(StockDescription, CASE WHEN 

LEN(StockDescription) - CHARINDEX(',', StockDescription) - 1 < 0 THEN 1 ELSE 
LEN(StockDescription) - CHARINDEX(',', StockDescription) - 1 END))) as 
'Knife Model'
,PrevFinishDate
,PrevOperation
,PrevWorkCentre
,InspectionSpecification_No
,InspectionSpecification_type
,Status
,CASE WHEN LAG(WJAL.OperCompleted) OVER (PARTITION BY WJAL.Job Order By 
WJAL.Operation) IS NULL THEN 'Y' ELSE LAG(WJAL.OperCompleted) OVER 
(PARTITION BY WJAL.Job Order By WJAL.Operation) END as PrevCompleted

From (Select Job
            ,Operation
            ,IExpUnitRunTim
            ,ParentQtyPlanEnt
            ,OperCompleted
            ,QtyCompleted
            ,QtyScrapped
            ,WorkCentre
            ,ActualFinishDate
            ,LAG(ActualFinishDate) OVER (PARTITION BY Job Order By 
Operation) as PrevFinishDate
            ,LAG(Operation) OVER (PARTITION BY Job Order By Operation) as 
PrevOperation
            ,LAG(WorkCentre) OVER (PARTITION BY Job Order By Operation) as 
PrevWorkCentre
        From CompanyH.dbo.WipJobAllLab) WJAL
Join CompanyH.dbo.WipMaster t2
On WJAL.Job = t2.Job
Join [uniPoint_CompanyH].[dbo].[PT_InspectionSpecification] t3
On Case
WHEN t2.Warehouse = 'RD' and StockCode = t3.Part COLLATE 
Latin1_General_BIN and t3.InspectionSpecification_type = 'First 
Article' THEN 1
WHEN t2.Warehouse <> 'RD' and StockCode = t3.Part COLLATE 
Latin1_General_BIN and t3.InspectionSpecification_type = 'In 
Process'  THEN 1
ELSE 0
END = 1
WHERE WorkCentre = 'INSPCT' and OperCompleted = 'N' and Complete = 'N' and 
t3.Status <> 'Obsolete'
UNION
Select  WJAL2.Job
,StockCode
,StockDescription
,Complete
,WJAL2.Operation
,IExpUnitRunTim
,ParentQtyPlanEnt
,OperCompleted
,QtyCompleted
,QtyScrapped
,WorkCentre
,JobStartDate
,ActualFinishDate
,LEFT(RIGHT(StockDescription, CASE WHEN 
                                LEN(StockDescription) - CHARINDEX(',', 
StockDescription) - 1 < 0 THEN 0 ELSE LEN(StockDescription) - CHARINDEX(',', 
StockDescription) - 1 END), CHARINDEX(' ', RIGHT(StockDescription, CASE WHEN 

LEN(StockDescription) - CHARINDEX(',', StockDescription) - 1 < 0 THEN 1 ELSE 
LEN(StockDescription) - CHARINDEX(',', StockDescription) - 1 END))) as 
'Knife Model'

,CASE WHEN LAG(OperCompleted) OVER (PARTITION BY WJAL2.Job Order By 
WJAL2.Operation) IS NULL THEN 'Y' ELSE LAG(OperCompleted) OVER (PARTITION BY 
WJAL2.Job Order By WJAL2.Operation) END as PrevCompleted
,PrevFinishDate
,PrevOperation
,PrevWorkCentre
,InspectionSpecification_No
,InspectionSpecification_type
,Status
From (Select Job
        ,Operation
        ,IExpUnitRunTim
        ,ParentQtyPlanEnt
        ,OperCompleted
        ,QtyCompleted
        ,QtyScrapped
        ,WorkCentre
        ,ActualFinishDate
        ,LAG(ActualFinishDate) OVER (PARTITION BY Job Order By Operation) as 
PrevFinishDate
        ,LAG(Operation) OVER (PARTITION BY Job Order By Operation) as 
PrevOperation
        ,LAG(WorkCentre) OVER (PARTITION BY Job Order By Operation) as 
PrevWorkCentre
    From CompanyH.dbo.WipJobAllLab) WJAL2
Join CompanyH.dbo.WipMaster t5
On WJAL2.Job = t5.Job
LEFT Join [uniPoint_CompanyH].[dbo].[PT_InspectionSpecification] t6
On t5.StockCode = t6.Part COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN
WHERE WorkCentre = 'INSPCT' and OperCompleted = 'N' and Complete = 'N'  and 
t6.InspectionSpecification_No is NULL
```

Comment: What happens if you use Union All instead of Union and wrap your query in a select distinct * from (< your query > ) tbl

Comment: First, work out which _column_ is causing the error by testing the union with individual columns. The problem is that you are unioning a numeric column with a varchar column and it is trying to convert the varchar to a numeric value. You need to explicitly do it the other way - convert the numeric column to a varchar value.

Comment: Short story: don't cast the fields to INT's - that's the problem. Instead cast the INT's to VARCHARs. This will stop the error but you probably won't get the result you expect.

Comment: Make sure you don't have two field names gobbled up without a comma. Such as MyInField1, MyIntField2 MyIntField3 MyVarcharField...

Comment: Add collate in the select part.
select a collate Latin1_General_BIN, b collate Latin1_General_BIN
from ...
union
select a collate Latin1_General_BIN, b collate Latin1_General_BIN
from ...

Comment: No amount of collates will fix an implicit conversion from varchar to numeric, which is what this problem is.

Comment: So Shiv's idea worked so far as I can tell. It did cause an issue with some of my columns losing their names. Which if all else fails I can just name outside the query. I plan to try some of the other ideas and see if any of those do the trick. Thanks for the info so far everyone. I will keep you posted.

Comment: Here is the same question with answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53074237/collation-conflict-in-stored-procedure/53080501#53080501

Answer (score 0):

The first error is pretty clear - its an issue with the union.

Remember that a union also removes duplicates, which means it has to compare every element in the first query with every element in the second. So as one of the comments says, add your collate modifier in the select lists for all varchar columns from your external table, as well as the explicit comparisons.

Second issue is probably caused by the same thing - when it tries to compare result set 1 with result set 2 during the union, if the first is an int and second a varchar, and some of the second are not numeric, you will get the error.