# Collation conflict in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

My stored procedure is throwing an error while executing:

> ERROR: UNABLE TO CREATE DELIMITED TEXT FILE (Reason: Implicit conversion of varchar value to varchar cannot be performed because the collation of the value is unresolved due to a collation conflict between "Latin1_General_CI_AI" and "Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_KS_WS_SC" in UNION ALL operator.)

My stored procedure basically creates a delimited file and takes a table or view as input along with filename.

I know it's a collation issue, but I have tried placing `Collate Database_Default` and `Collate Catalog_Default` in the query, but the error is not resolved by that.

Can anyone please guide me as to what I am doing wrong?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE Usp_Delfile
     (@Source VARCHAR(MAX),
      @DestinationFile VARCHAR(MAX),
      @ColumnList VARCHAR(MAX) = '',
      @Delimiter VARCHAR(256) = ',',
      @Qualifier VARCHAR(256) = '"',
      @Criteria VARCHAR(MAX) = '',
      @FirstRow INT = 0,
      @LastRow INT = 0,
      @Username VARCHAR(256) = '',
      @Password VARCHAR(256) = '',
      @Server VARCHAR(256) = '',
      @SourceType VARCHAR(100) = '',
      @SourceTableName VARCHAR(128) = '',
      @OtherConnection VARCHAR(MAX) = '')
AS
BEGIN
    -- Declare variable
    DECLARE @HeaderCount INT
    DECLARE @Header VARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @COLNAME VARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @SUBSQL VARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @TEMPVIEWNAME VARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @counter INT

    -- Otherconnection is not used but kept for future development
    SET @OtherConnection = ''

    -- Set the name of the temporary view
    SET @TEMPVIEWNAME = 'uTEMPVIEW'+convert(varchar(max),newid())

BEGIN TRY
    -- Try to figure out the source type in case one is not given and it appears something other than SQL may be given
    BEGIN TRY
    IF (charindex('\',@SOURCE) > 0 AND charindex('.', reverse(@SOURCE)) = 4 AND @SourceType='')
    BEGIN
        SET @SourceType = SUBSTRING(UPPER(@SOURCE),LEN(@SOURCE)-2,3)
    END
    ELSE
        SET @SourceType = 'SQL'
end try
begin catch
-- If an error occurs during this time, ignore it and assume SQL source type
  SET @SourceType = 'SQL'
end catch


IF (UPPER(@SourceType) <> 'SQL')
BEGIN
  IF (@OtherConnection <> '')
    -- This will be used in the future but disabled for now from previous set statement (I left this in here because I have a horrible memory!)
    exec ('create view ['+@TEMPVIEWNAME+'-other] as (select * from OpenRowset('+@OtherConnection+'))')
  ELSE
  BEGIN
    -- If the source is a delimited file, create a view to the file
    DECLARE @filepath varchar(256)
    DECLARE @filename varchar(256)
    DECLARE @OtherViewSQL varchar(max)

    -- Get the file path and filename
    select @filepath=reverse(substring(reverse(@Source), charindex('\', reverse(@Source))+1, len(@Source) - charindex('\', reverse(@Source)) ))
    select @filename=reverse(substring(reverse(@Source), 0, charindex('\', reverse(@Source)) ))
    -- Create view to the file using its connector
    If(UPPER(@SourceType) = 'DELIMITED' OR UPPER(@SourceType) = 'CSV' OR Upper(@SourceType) = 'TEXT' OR Upper(@SourceType) = 'TXT')
    exec('create view ['+@TEMPVIEWNAME+'-other] as (select * from OpenRowset(''MSDASQL'', ''Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)};DefaultDir='+@filepath+';'',''select * from ['+@filename+']''))')
    else if(UPPER(@SourceType) = 'DBF' OR UPPER(@SourceType) = 'DBASE' OR UPPER(@SourceType) = 'DBASE3' OR UPPER(@SourceType) = 'DBASEIII' OR UPPER(@SourceType) = 'DBASE 3' OR UPPER(@SourceType) = 'DBASE III' OR UPPER(@SourceType) = 'FOXPRO')
    exec('create view ['+@TEMPVIEWNAME+'-other] as (select * from OpenRowset(''MSDASQL'', ''Driver={Microsoft dBase Driver (*.dbf)};DBQ='+@filepath+';'',''select * from ['+@filename+']''))')
    else IF(UPPER(@SourceType) = 'ACCESS' OR UPPER(@SourceType) = 'MDB')
    exec('create view ['+@TEMPVIEWNAME+'-other] as (select * from OpenRowset(''MICROSOFT.JET.OLEDB.4.0'', '''+@filepath+'\'+@filename+''' ;;,['+@SourceTableName+']))')
    else IF(UPPER(@SourceType) = 'EXCEL' OR UPPER(@SourceType) = 'XLS')
    exec('create view ['+@TEMPVIEWNAME+'-other] as (select * from OpenRowset(''MICROSOFT.JET.OLEDB.4.0'', ''Excel 8.0;DATABASE='+@filepath+'\'+@filename+''',''select * from ['+@SourceTableName+'$]''))')
  END


-- Set the source table to the new view
SET @Source = @TEMPVIEWNAME+'-other'

END
ELSE
  SET @SourceTableName = @Source

-- Check to see if columnlist is provided
IF (@ColumnList <> '')
  BEGIN
    -- Get header count from columnlist
    SELECT @HeaderCount = ((LEN(RTRIM(LTRIM(@ColumnList))) - LEN(REPLACE(RTRIM(LTRIM(@ColumnList)), ',', '')))+1)

    -- Build delimited file header row
    SELECT @Header = COALESCE(@Header  + ',', '') + 
      CASE WHEN @Qualifier = '' THEN ' '''+@Qualifier+'''+CASE when isnumeric(['+column_name+']) = 1 AND
    case when exists(select ordinal_position  from 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where Upper(table_name) = '''+Upper((REPLACE(REPLACE(@Source,'[',''),']','')))+''' 
    and (UPPER(data_type)  <> ''VARCHAR'' OR UPPER(data_type)  <> ''NVARCHAR'' OR UPPER(data_type)  <> ''CHAR'' OR UPPER(data_type)  <>''NCHAR'') 
    and Upper(column_name) ='''+UPPER(column_name) COLLATE CATALOG_DEFAULT +''') THEN -1 ELSE 0
    END = 0
    THEN cast(cast(['+column_name+']  as decimal(38, 38)) as varchar(max)) ELSE cast(CASE when ['+column_name+']  = '''' THEN NULL ELSE ['+column_name+']  END as varchar(max)) END+'''+@Qualifier+''' as ['+column_name+']'
    ELSE ' '''+@Qualifier+'''+ISNULL(CASE when isnumeric(['+column_name+']) = 1 AND
    case when exists(select ordinal_position  from 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where Upper(table_name)  = '''+Upper((REPLACE(REPLACE(@Source,'[',''),']','')))+''' 
    and (UPPER(data_type) <> ''VARCHAR'' OR UPPER(data_type) <> ''NVARCHAR'' OR UPPER(data_type) <> ''CHAR'' OR UPPER(data_type) <>''NCHAR'') 
    and Upper(column_name)='''+UPPER(column_name)+''') THEN -1 ELSE 0
    END = 0
    THEN cast(cast(['+column_name+'] as decimal(38, 38)) as varchar(max)) ELSE cast(CASE when ['+column_name+'] = '''' THEN NULL ELSE ['+column_name+'] END as varchar(max)) END,'''')+'''+@Qualifier+''' as ['+column_name+']'
        END
    FROM ( SELECT column_name, rank() OVER (ORDER BY ordinal_position) as rank
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns
    where UPPER(table_name) = Upper((REPLACE(REPLACE(@Source,'[',''),']',''))) AND charindex(','+column_name+',',RTRIM(LTRIM(','+@ColumnList+','))) > 0
    ) t ORDER BY t.rank ASC 

    -- Initialize main view query
    SET @SQL = 'SELECT '

    -- Build main view query
    set @counter = 0
    while @counter < @HeaderCount
      begin
        -- Increase counter
        set @counter = @counter + 1
        -- Get column name
        SELECT TOP 1 @colname = column_name FROM ( SELECT TOP (@counter) column_name, rank() OVER (ORDER BY ordinal_position) as rank
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns
        where UPPER(table_name) = ((Upper((REPLACE(REPLACE(@Source,'[',''),']',''))))) AND charindex(','+column_name+',',RTRIM(LTRIM(','+@ColumnList+','))) > 0
        ORDER BY rank ASC ) as t ORDER BY rank DESC
        -- Add to main view query
        IF @counter = @HeaderCount
          BEGIN
            SET @SQL = @SQL + ''''+@Qualifier+'''+ SUBSTRING(RTRIM(LTRIM('''+@ColumnList+''')),charindex('''+@colname+''',RTRIM(LTRIM('''+@ColumnList+'''))), LEN('''+@colname+'''))+'''+@Qualifier+''' as ['+@colname+'] '
          END
        ELSE
          BEGIN
            SET @SQL = @SQL + ''''+@Qualifier+'''+ SUBSTRING(RTRIM(LTRIM('''+@ColumnList+''')),charindex('''+@colname+''',RTRIM(LTRIM('''+@ColumnList+'''))), LEN('''+@colname+'''))+'''+@Qualifier+''' as ['+@colname+@Delimiter+'], '
          END
      end
  END
ELSE
  BEGIN
    -- Get header count from columnlist
    SELECT @HeaderCount = count(column_name)
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns
    where UPPER(table_name) = Upper((REPLACE(REPLACE(@Source,'[',''),']','')))

    -- Build delimited file header row
    SELECT @Header = COALESCE(@Header  + ',', '') + 
      CASE WHEN @Qualifier = '' THEN ' '''+@Qualifier+'''+CASE when isnumeric(['+column_name+']) = 1 AND 
    case when exists(select ordinal_position from 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where Upper(table_name) COLLATE CATALOG_DEFAULT = '''+Upper((REPLACE(REPLACE(@Source,'[',''),']','')))+''' 
    and (UPPER(data_type) <> ''VARCHAR'' OR UPPER(data_type) <> ''NVARCHAR'' OR UPPER(data_type) <> ''CHAR'' OR UPPER(data_type) <>''NCHAR'') 
    and Upper(column_name)='''+UPPER(column_name)+''') THEN -1 ELSE 0
    END = 0
    THEN cast(cast(['+column_name+'] as decimal(38, 38)) as varchar(max)) ELSE cast(CASE when ['+column_name+'] = '''' THEN NULL ELSE ['+column_name+'] END as varchar(max)) END+'''+@Qualifier+''' as ['+column_name+']'
    ELSE ' '''+@Qualifier+'''+ISNULL(CASE when isnumeric(['+column_name+']) = 1 AND 
    case when exists(select ordinal_position from 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where Upper(table_name) = '''+Upper((REPLACE(REPLACE(@Source,'[',''),']','')))+''' 
    and (UPPER(data_type) <> ''VARCHAR'' OR UPPER(data_type) <> ''NVARCHAR'' OR UPPER(data_type) <> ''CHAR'' OR UPPER(data_type) <>''NCHAR'') 
    and Upper(column_name)='''+UPPER(column_name)+''') THEN -1 ELSE 0
    END = 0
    THEN cast(cast(['+column_name+'] as decimal(38, 38)) as varchar(max)) ELSE cast(CASE when cast(['+column_name +'] as varchar(max)) = '''' THEN NULL ELSE ['+column_name+'] END as varchar(max)) END,'''')+'''+@Qualifier+''' as ['+column_name+']'
    END
    FROM ( SELECT column_name, rank() OVER (ORDER BY ordinal_position) as rank
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns
    where UPPER(table_name) = Upper((REPLACE(REPLACE(@Source,'[',''),']','')))
    ) t ORDER BY t.rank ASC 
    -- Initialize main view query
    SET @SQL = 'SELECT '

    -- Build main view query
    set @counter = 0

    while @counter < @HeaderCount
      begin
        -- Increase counter
        set @counter = @counter + 1
        -- Get column name
        SELECT TOP 1 @colname = column_name  FROM ( SELECT TOP (@counter) column_name, rank() OVER (ORDER BY ordinal_position) as rank
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns
        where UPPER(table_name) = Upper((REPLACE(REPLACE(@Source,'[',''),']','')))
        ORDER BY rank ASC ) as t ORDER BY rank DESC

        -- Add to main view query
        IF @counter = @HeaderCount
          BEGIN
            SET @SQL = @SQL + ''''+@Qualifier+'''+ cast(min(case ordinal_position when '+cast(@counter as varchar)+' then column_name end) as varchar)   +'''+@Qualifier+''' as ['+@colname+'] '
          END
        ELSE
          BEGIN
            SET @SQL = @SQL + ''''+@Qualifier+'''+cast(min(case ordinal_position  when '+cast(@counter as varchar)+' then column_name end) as varchar)  +'''+@Qualifier+''' as ['+@colname+'], '
          END
      end

    SET @SQL = @SQL + ' from ['+db_name()+'].information_schema.columns where UPPER(table_name) = Upper('''+Upper((REPLACE(REPLACE(@Source,'[',''),']','')))+''') '

  END
-- Finish up the main view query
SET @SQL = @SQL + ' union all '
SET @SQL = @SQL + ' select '
SET @SQL = @SQL + @Header + ' FROM ['+db_name()+']..['+Upper((REPLACE(REPLACE(@Source,'[',''),']','')))+']'

-- Add criteria if exists
IF (@Criteria <> '')
BEGIN
  SET @SQL = @SQL + ' WHERE '+@Criteria+' '
END

-- Create temporary view
exec('create view ['+@TEMPVIEWNAME+'] as ('+@SQL+')')

-- Execute bcp on temporary view
DECLARE @bcpcmd varchar(8000)
SET @bcpcmd = 'bcp ["'+db_name()+']..['+@TEMPVIEWNAME+']" out "'+@DestinationFile+'" -k -c ACP -t "'+@Delimiter+'"'
-- Add first row and last row arguments to bcp command
IF (@FirstRow > 0)
SET @bcpcmd = @bcpcmd + ' -F '+cast(@FirstRow as varchar)
IF (@LastRow > 0)
SET @bcpcmd = @bcpcmd + ' -L '+cast(@LastRow as varchar)


-- Add server login information
IF (@Username <> '')
BEGIN
  SET @bcpcmd = @bcpcmd + ' -U '+@Username
  IF (@Password <> '')
  SET @bcpcmd = @bcpcmd + ' -P '+@Password
END
ELSE
BEGIN
  SET @bcpcmd = @bcpcmd + ' -T '
END

IF (@Server <> '')
SET @bcpcmd = @bcpcmd + ' -S '+@Server

exec master..xp_cmdshell @bcpcmd

-- Drop temporary view

exec('IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.views WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'''+@TEMPVIEWNAME+''')) DROP View ['+@TEMPVIEWNAME+']')
exec('IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.views WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'''+@TEMPVIEWNAME+'-other'')) DROP VIEW ['+@TEMPVIEWNAME+'-other]')
end try
begin catch
  -- show error if one occurs
  SELECT 'ERROR: UNABLE TO CREATE DELIMITED TEXT FILE (Reason:' + error_message() + ')'
  begin try
    -- Drop view if an error occurs
    exec('IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.views WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'''+@TEMPVIEWNAME+''')) DROP View ['+@TEMPVIEWNAME+']')
    exec('IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.views WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'''+@TEMPVIEWNAME+'-other'')) DROP VIEW ['+@TEMPVIEWNAME+'-other]')
  end try
  begin catch
  end catch
end catch
END
```

Comment: My guess would be that you have a temp table of a different collation in the mix. Temp tables table the collation of the temp database, not the main database you are using. However I think its going to be very difficult for anyone to offer you more advise than that given the complexity of your SQL. You just have to debug it the old fashioned way, build up your code a block at a time to identify the exact location of the odd collation failure.

Comment: The error says that the conflict occurs in UNION ALL, and you have only one union all in your query. Try to print @SQL after the assignment `SET @SQL = @SQL + @Header + ' FROM ['+db_name()+']..['+Upper((REPLACE(REPLACE(@Source,'[',''),']','')))+']'`, copy it and try to execute, the conflict is here

Comment: @sepupic That's the right solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you apply union in sql query it might demand each field in union query must be with same details. e.g number of fields, data type of the respective fields.

Your error says collation of value is different. You have to make same collation for columns in both query.

Below change in script could fix your problem.

```
IF @counter = @HeaderCount
  BEGIN
    SET @SQL = @SQL + ''''+@Qualifier+'''+ cast(min(case ordinal_position when '+cast(@counter as varchar)+' then column_name Collate Latin1_General_CI_AI end) as varchar)   +'''+@Qualifier+''' as ['+@colname+'] '
  END
ELSE
  BEGIN
    SET @SQL = @SQL + ''''+@Qualifier+'''+cast(min(case ordinal_position  when '+cast(@counter as varchar)+' then column_name Collate Latin1_General_CI_AI end) as varchar)  +'''+@Qualifier+''' as ['+@colname+'], '
  END
```